# ggplot2- Not sure how to get rid of lines on interactive plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

My plot adds lines connecting the data points, but I just want the data points with no lines connecting them. How would I change my code to make the lines connecting the points disappear? Below is my code and what the plot looks like with data inserted

```
ucsplot <- ggplot(data1()$dfplot, aes(data1()$ucs,data1()$depth)) +   
    annotate("rect", xmin=0, xmax=3700, ymin=max(data1()$dfplot[,1])+10, ymax=min(data1()$dfplot[,1])-15, fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2)+
    annotate("rect", xmin=3700, xmax=7000, ymin=max(data1()$dfplot[,1])+10, ymax=min(data1()$dfplot[,1])-15, fill = "gray50", alpha = 0.2)+
    annotate("rect", xmin=7000, xmax=15000, ymin=max(data1()$dfplot[,1])+10, ymax=min(data1()$dfplot[,1])-15, fill = "green", alpha = 0.2)+
    annotate("rect", xmin=15000, xmax=35000, ymin=max(data1()$dfplot[,1])+10, ymax=min(data1()$dfplot[,1])-15, fill = "darkorange", alpha = 0.2)+
    annotate("rect", xmin=35000, xmax=475000, ymin=max(data1()$dfplot[,1])+10, ymax=min(data1()$dfplot[,1])-15, fill = "red", alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_path() + xlab("UCS (psi)") + ylab("Depth (ft)") + labs(title=paste(data1()$well[1], " Depth vs. UCS", sep="")) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5)) +
    geom_point_interactive(aes(tooltip = data1()$dfplot[,1], data_id = data1()$dfplot[,1]), size = .75) +
    scale_x_continuous(position = "top", limits = c(0, max(data1()$dfplot[,3]+5000)), expand=c(0,0)) +
    scale_y_reverse(limits = c(max(data1()$dfplot[,1])+10, min(data1()$dfplot[,1])-15 ), expand = c(0, 0)) +
    geom_text(aes(x=1850, y=min(data1()$dfplot[,1]-10), label="Very Weak"), size=3) +
    geom_text(aes(x=5350, y=min(data1()$dfplot[,1]-10), label="Weak"), size=3) +
    geom_text(aes(x=11000, y=min(data1()$dfplot[,1]-10), label="Fair"), size=3) +
    geom_text(aes(x=25000, y=min(data1()$dfplot[,1]-10), label="Strong"), size=3) +
    geom_text(aes(x=41250, y=min(data1()$dfplot[,1]-10), label="Very Strong"), size=3)

ggiraph(code = print(ucsplot), hover_css = "cursor:pointer;fill:red;stroke:red;")
```

[image: Plot with lines]

Comment: drop the `geom_path()` layer

Comment: If I drop the `geom_path()` layer, then my data won't be in the original order in which I want it presented

Comment: really? that's weird, could you add some data to make an example plot (doesn't have to be the whole thing) and we can get all of the plotting order problems straightened out

Comment: It's a pretty drawn out program in shiny, so I'm not sure I can provide data.

Comment: Just show a representative subset of data, we don't need your whole shiny application, we don't need your whole data. Just give us 10-20 rows of data, shared with `dput()` so it is copy/pasteable.

Comment: Also, I would strongly recommend creating a separate data frame for all your `geom_text` layers. A quick little subset would turn that into a single layer and avoid the overplotting which makes the text on the graph look all pixelated.